When will the exclusive Pokemon Go Fest raids be released globally?
The yearly Go Fest event features raids at certain real-world locations. Those event-exclusive Pokemon are eventually released globally/worldwide so that everyone can have a chance to battle and catch them. This year, the featured Pokemon is Necrozma.
I recently watched Mystic7's video where he caught Necrozma at the Go Fest which got me wondering: when are the Necrozma raids being released globally? Or did I already miss it?

According to official news:
In-person raids were available at Go Fest 2024 in Sendai City, Madrid, and New York City, in early May.
Globally available raids will start on July 13th/14th with Pokemon Go Fest Day 2: Global.

Next month, right?

Yes, about 28 days from today (as they use local time for players, so timezones matter).
